# Displaying total time android leanback

Tags: android, android-video-player, leanback

I have a simple Android tv leanback app that displays videos. The video player works fine and displays necessary controls. However, I wanted to add the total duration of a video on the right side of the PlaybackControlsRow but don't know how. I am using this code to setup the PlaybackControlRow

```
private void addPlaybackControlsRow() {
        /* movieItem data must have newly allocated area, do not refer existing movie (ex. mItems.get(0))
           since this item will be overwritten later */
        Movie movieItem = new Movie();
        mPlaybackControlsRow = new PlaybackControlsRow(movieItem);
        mRowsAdapter.add(mPlaybackControlsRow);

        ControlButtonPresenterSelector presenterSelector = new ControlButtonPresenterSelector();
        mPrimaryActionsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(presenterSelector);
        mSecondaryActionsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(presenterSelector);
        mPlaybackControlsRow.setPrimaryActionsAdapter(mPrimaryActionsAdapter);
        mPlaybackControlsRow.setSecondaryActionsAdapter(mSecondaryActionsAdapter);

        Activity activity = getActivity();
        mPlayPauseAction = new PlaybackControlsRow.PlayPauseAction(activity);
        mRepeatAction = new PlaybackControlsRow.RepeatAction(activity);
        mThumbsUpAction = new PlaybackControlsRow.ThumbsUpAction(activity);
        mThumbsDownAction = new PlaybackControlsRow.ThumbsDownAction(activity);
        mShuffleAction = new PlaybackControlsRow.ShuffleAction(activity);
        mSkipNextAction = new PlaybackControlsRow.SkipNextAction(activity);
        mSkipPreviousAction = new PlaybackControlsRow.SkipPreviousAction(activity);
        mFastForwardAction = new PlaybackControlsRow.FastForwardAction(activity);
        mRewindAction = new PlaybackControlsRow.RewindAction(activity);


        /* PrimaryAction setting */
        mPrimaryActionsAdapter.add(mSkipPreviousAction);
        mPrimaryActionsAdapter.add(mRewindAction);
        mPrimaryActionsAdapter.add(mPlayPauseAction);
        mPrimaryActionsAdapter.add(mFastForwardAction);
        mPrimaryActionsAdapter.add(mSkipNextAction);
    }
```

I set the current time and also tried setting the total time like this:

```
int currentTime = mPlaybackController.getCurrentPosition();
int totalTime = mPlaybackControlsRow.getTotalTime();
mPlaybackControlsRow.setCurrentTime(currentTime);
mPlaybackControlsRow.setTotalTime(totalTime);
```

And the video player looks like this:
[image: Current video player]

As you can see, I can't get the total time on the right side of the *PlaybackControlsRow*. How can I fix this?

Comment: After changing the time, do you let the adapter know it's changed? There was a call on the mRowsAdapter that you needed to call, something like metaChanged or similar if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Ewald, yes that was the problem. I have added an answer to my question. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Yes, I got tripped up by that gem as well. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getDuration()` and `setDuration(long)` since `getTotalTime()` and `setTotalTime()` were deprecated in API level 26.0.0.

Reference: [PlaybackControlsRow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/PlaybackControlsRow.html)

Comment: I am using API level 25.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

As user @Ewald commented, I forgot to notify the `mRowsAdapter` object. If you are using API level 25 and less, when you call `setTotalTime(totalTime)` on a `PlaybackControlsRow` object, you must notify the adapter to see the changes. Here is the documentation on `setTotalTime` method

> Sets the total time in milliseconds for the playback controls row.
>
> If set after the row has been bound to a view, the adapter must be
>   notified that this row has changed.

Hence, I notified the adapter like this

```
mRowsAdapter.notifyArrayItemRangeChanged(0, mRowsAdapter.size());
```

And now I get the total time. Hope this helps someone.